# If I import a module, will the compiled python file contain the bytecode of the code inside the module?

Tags: python, math, module, bytecode

```
import math

print(math.sqrt(9))
```

I read that the python script is first compiled and converted to bytecode. Does the file containing the bytecode - *I guess .pyi* - also contain the bytecode of the `math` module along with the bytecode of `print(math.sqrt(9))`?

Comment: No it does not also contain it.

Comment: @martineau So it just contains the bytecode of ```print(math.sqrt(9))```, right?

Comment: Yes, the byte-code compiled library module & function is stored elsewhere.